# Titanium KitchenSink starts then closes on Galaxy S2 device

Tags: android, titanium

I am new to Titanium Studio. 
Have done "hello" app in Elipse/ADT and successfully deployed on Galaxy S2 (4.0.3). 
When I do Titanium "Welcome" example or "KitchenSink" they work OK in the emulator but on the S2 they start up and immediately close without waiting for any events.
I see a Titanium splash screen then the initial View then back to home screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The kitchen sink is not meant for deploying. It is also not meant to be a good example on how to build an app. It is an app that displays the functionality, and from that you can create your own app

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. 
Would you say the same for the "Welcome to Titanium" app? It behaves the same (incorrect) way.
On the other hand the "Hello" app I did with Eclipse/MDDS behaves identically in both the virtual and physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink

Download latest build from here. 
make sure your cell phone not be rooted.

Comment: Thanks - same with latest build. But I put it on someone else's Samsung (GT-I1850T) and it works. It is running Ver 2.3.6 instead of 4.0.3 for what that is worth. Odd that Titanium apps crash on the S2 but Eclipse/ADT apps work. 
Next I will force a factory reset on the S2. I want to fix it and I want to know why.

Comment: Further info - when you start ANY Titanium App on this particular Galaxy S2 you see the splash screen then the first window appears for a fraction of a second before it dies. One of the apps has been developed by someone using an S2

Comment: you are doing something wrong. may be in creating window or may be in deploying. check your code again. it works on all version of sgs2/android. i am personally using s2(official 4.0.3) and its working fine

Comment: Terrible newbie stuff-up. I reluctantly reset the RAM to factory settings and I am now in business. Except I have to reload all my apps :-(

Comment: THanks for trying to help. You can give me -1 for this!